# Load div content with jQuery by deafult

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show `#destiny2` on page load. The `#destiny2` contains some text and images, other content for any 3 categories. I have to click on category element to show it - it's necessery to show first content without clicking, after page load (show the first category by default) and show other two categories content after clicking category name as it works now.

I'm sure the `$window(onload)` should repair it, but it doesn't work for me...

This is my code:

```
if($(response).hasClass('one')){
    $('.ajax-destiny #destiny1').empty();
    var odp = $('.ajax-destiny #destiny2').empty().append(response).parent().addClass('height');
    $(odp).find('.one > #cont').append($('#information').html());
} else {
    $('.ajax-destiny #destiny2').empty();
    $('.ajax-destiny #destiny1').empty().append(response).parent().addClass('height');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$window(onload)` - that's not even the correct syntax, should be

```
window.onload = function() 
    {
        // code to display #destiny2
    };`
```

However, that's not the best way to go about it; I'm not sure if it's not deprecated...

What you can also try is `$(document).ready(...)`, which is actually my preferred way.
The syntax there is:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    // code to display #destiny2
};
```

Add it at the start of you javascript file. This will display it once the whole document is loaded, so it will avoid trying to display an element before it's ready. [Documentation here.](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)